# RestAPI - как реализовать возврат данных?

Tags: php, laravel, api, rest

В общем делаю проект на Laravel с RestApi и vuejs. Возврат products делаю с использованием ApiResource в Laravel. Т.е. проблем никаких не возникает. Но вот возник вопрос в том, что на странице списков товаров возвращаются ненужные данные. Например: на странице категории товаров на фронте выводится только имя товара, и, скажем, имя его  категории, но сам эндпоинт возвращает также дескрипшн и т.д., что собственно увеличит вес запроса. С одной стороны решение тут очевидно, - ограничить вывод для конкретного эндпоинта, но в этом случае будет нарушен принцип, согласно которому бэкенд ничего не должен знать о фронтэнде, и наоборот. Решение с гет-параметрами определяющими выборку - также нарушает этот принцип.
В общем суть вопроса в решении вот этой дилеммы. Я лично склоняюсь к тому, что бэк возвращает данные, а реализация клиентской части забирает уже их и обрабатывает как ей нужно. Кто сталкивался, подскажите )

Comment: Если лишние 3 килобайта Вам сильно мешают, то что-то придётся нарушить. Хотя, почему решение с гет-параметрами (или построенными параметрами через роутеры) что-то нарушает? Бэк получил данные и обработал, непосредственно о фронте он по-прежнему ничего не знает.

Comment: Согласен с Vladimir Gonchar в том плане, что вес ответа не увеличится на столько, что бы это хоть как-то повлияло на производительность. Но если прям хоцца, то копните в сторону graphql. Там вы сами решаете шо и как вам сервер отдаст. Я не силён в Лаве, но вот даже обёрточку нашёл https://github.com/rebing/graphql-laravel. Правда это уже будет не совсем restful.

Comment: @Vladimir Gonchar Самое забавное, что лично меня килобайты не беспокоят, т.к. сейчас не  2001 год. это прилетают комментарии от ПМа, который, не вцепился в эти килобайты, и я,  собственно, решил узнать как вообще в мире делают, потому как в бестпрактис  я не видел, чтобы кто-то кидал уточняющие параметры, ну кроме фильтров. С параметрами, помоему, это уже не рест, там что-то другое было.
Решение с уточняющими параметрами, предполагает осведомленность фронта о струкутре сущности на беке, поэтому не нравится. Ну в целом я услышал что хотел - эти потери незначительны )

Comment: @Kirill да, точно, graphql эти вопросы решает. В целом согласен с тем, что там потерь сильных не должно быть. Спасибо за ответ )

Comment: API Platform вам в руки